Hide "Favorite/Unfavorite" button in ribbon via list view format CommandBarProps
Need to hide majority of button in library ribbon - using "Format View" option and JSON editor work for every button.. except "Favorite" and "Unfavorite".
Syntax reference does not have any indication of these buttons. Tried different values (favorite, unfavorite, follow, unfollow,..) for keys in JSON, but without result.
What value should be passed as key to target these buttons?
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "{what-to-put-here-to-target-favorite-and-unfavorite}",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}



Are these "Favorite" and "Unfavorite" options SharePoint default OR created using custom SPFx list view command set? As per the documentation, it seems currently it is not supported to hide these options using command bar JSON formatting.

Out-of-box obviously - it would not make sense to create custom buttons and try to hide via predefined key set. :)

Agree with @Ganesh Sanap. It is impossible to hide Favorite/Unfavorite using JSON view formatting.

As per my research, currently it is not supported to hide "Favorite" and "Unfavorite" options using SharePoint list view command bar JSON formatting.
You can try raising the new issue at SharePoint Developer Docs repository to get more information related to it from Microsoft or repository maintainers.
Also, this seems like a new feature request (enhancement) to SharePoint list view command bar JSON formatting functionality. So, I will suggest you to add new feedback/idea on SharePoint feedback portal as well.
Here is the link to portal: SharePoint Feedback Portal.
